# Modal dialog not showing

Tags: knockout.js

Modal dialog not visible from the button click in a knockout.js project

Here is my submit button:

```
   <button type="submit" class="btn" data-bind="enable: SubmitEnabled" style="margin-left:-10px;">Save Note</button>
```

If enabled and when clicked It would execute the addNotes function and in turn would call the insertnote to insert a note into the database. I wanted to add a confirmation modal dialog box but It would not showed when the button is clicked. What did I do wrong? What am I missing?

```
 self.SubmitEnabled = ko.observable(false);


 self.SubmitEnabled(true);
 self.addNotes = function () {
    // display confirmation 
      var warnningMsg = "A existing note found. Do you want to continue?";
            $('#popUpModal').find('.modal-body').text(warnningMsg);
            $('#popUpModal').modal('show');     

    InsertNote(s) (
      // ajax call to insert note into the database
     )
      
}
```

Here is the definition of the model dialog located in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
 <div id="popUpModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Existing Note Found!</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body"></div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Continue</button>
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use jQuery if you are using Knockout.js (KO) :) Use KO attributes to manipulate state of objects.

```js
class AppViewModel {
  constructor() {
    // Make button enabled by default
    this.SubmitEnabled = ko.observable(true);
    // dialog is hidden
    this.ConfirmationVisible = ko.observable(false);
  }

  // make confirmation dialog visible on button click
  saveNoteClicked() {
    this.ConfirmationVisible(true);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" data-bind="enable: SubmitEnabled, click: saveNoteClicked">Save Note</button>

<div data-bind="visible: ConfirmationVisible" id="popUpModal" class="modal fade">Confirm dialog window</div>
```

Comment: @Vasinov: I made some of the changes you suggested but the dialog still not showing.

Comment: I've updated my answer, so you could run it as a code snippet and check. I suggest you to add you HTML code to this code step by step.